# What is the best graph drawing package for web pages out there?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, graph, canvas

My main concern is not so much flexibility ( of course, that's given like zooming in, etc. ) but the memory leakage. I need something that I can leave on for days and with an every second update - it still needs to go strong.

Flot, JQplot, etc. are all on my radar.

Comment: "Best" by what criteria? Anything beyond "no memory leaks?"

Comment: The memory leak is the most important. But also the overall look of the graphs and the ability to drill down or get info for the mouseover points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been using [Google Charts](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) lately, although that probably doesn't meet your requirement of "every second update" because Google will notice this and most likely impose rate limits on you.

Comment: This is for commercial use. BTW, why in the world do you like Google Charts? That seems to be very unflexible one with very few features.